# Segoe MDL2 Assets - icon for change or reset password button

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

In my `UWP` app I am using [Segoe MDL2 Assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/segoe-mdl2-assets) for icons for various buttons. But I could not find such an icon for `Password Change` or `Reset Password` button. It would be something similar to a key image (shown below) as you may have seen in outlook profile where you change password. Or, something like [Font Awesome Icons](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/tryit.asp?filename=tryicons_fa-key) shown on web apps. Can someone point me to where I can get such a font that can be used as a button icon for UWP app? As some of you may have noticed we use entity code like `&#xE74E;` for such icons.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this document- [Segoe MDL2 Assets icons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font) for the icon Assets. The key icon's unicode point that you need is `E8D7`, it's description is `Permissions`.

[image]

Comment: Do you also happen to know one for NumberedList, Numbered Listt, Increase Indent, and Decrease Indent, as well? I've posted the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65598914/1232087)