# What are numbered list, Increase Indent, and Decrease Indent icons in Segoe MDL2 Assets?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

For our `UWP` app, where can we find the `Numbered Listt, Increase Indent, and Decrease Indent` icons in [Segoe MDL2 Assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font#icon-list)? This link has one icon for bulleted list but not for numbered list, Increase Indent, and Decrease Indent. Please note: we need it from `Segoe MDL2 Assets`. Otherwise, there are plenty of such icons available online.

Comment: You will not find every icon in Segoe MDL. the set is limited. There is a very helpful app in Windows store called `Dev Icons` containing all Segoe icons and easy to find and use features. You may try that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icons you're looking for are actually part of the Fabric MDL2 font, which you can create a custom version of here:

https://uifabricicons.azurewebsites.net/

(The free [Character Map UWP app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/character-map-uwp/9wzdncrdxf41?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) will let you search MDL2 font glyphs by name, and give you UWP code for using such icons)

Comment: 1) Where do you download `Fabric MDL2 font` from? My windows 10 doesn't have these installed? 2) Also, in a control, for `Segoe MDL2 Assets` you use FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets". What value do we use for FontFamily attribute for Fabric fonts?

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid you can’t find icons that exactly matches your requirement, I suggest you find icons with similar shape such as following icons in **Character Map** which is built-in in Windows 10.

```
<FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE290;" />
<FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE291;" />
<FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE8FD;" />
```

Result:

[image]